# Single File Generator not working for .NET Standard Projects in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsix, single-file-generator

I've implemented a Single File Generator based off the template [1] (that compiles into an installable VSIX output, including the automatic registration of the components) and:

- It works for classic .NET projects in VS 2015 and VS2017;
- It works for .NET Core projects in VS2017;
- But doesn't work for .NET Standard projects in VS2017.

[image: example]

All of the `HasCustomTool.xml` files have the same configuration, all of them have the 'Custom Tool' attribute specified.

When I look at the `.csproj` files, I can see that they are different. The (working) content of the `DotNetCore.csproj` file is:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="HasCustomTool.cs">
      <DependentUpon>HasCustomTool.xml</DependentUpon>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="HasCustomTool.xml">
      <LastGenOutput>HasCustomTool.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <Generator>PtResxErrorTool</Generator>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Whereas the `DotNetStandard.csproj` file has:

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <None Update="HasCustomTool.xml">
          <LastGenOutput>HasCustomTool.cs</LastGenOutput>
          <Generator>PtResxErrorTool</Generator>
      </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

When you copy over the markup from `DotNetCore.csproj` to the `DotNetStandard.csproj` (by hand), you get the desired structure -- but the generator is never activated.

Has anybody successfully written a VSIX single file generator for .NET Standard projects? Any pointers on how to debug this problem?

[1] https://github.com/Microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/Single_File_Generator

Comment: I had a similar but not identical issue running custom tools - my fix was to install VS2015 on my PC, which previously had only ever had VS2017 installed. Full details of the issue are located at https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/72482/custom-tool-not-found.html?childToView=73591#comment-73591

Comment: See also similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616852/visual-studio-2017-wont-run-custom-tool-in-net-standard-library

Comment: How did you get to first base with this project?  The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop is incompatible with .NET Standard versions.  At least that's what the NuGet loader is telling me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a new CodeGeneratorRegistration to your class.

"{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}"

in my case my class decl looked like

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid(GuidList.GuidI18NReactivetring)]
[ProvideObject(typeof(I18NReactive))]
[CodeGeneratorRegistration(typeof(I18NReactive), "I18N.Reactive", vsContextGuids.vsContextGuidVCSProject, GeneratesDesignTimeSource = true)]
[CodeGeneratorRegistration(typeof(I18NReactive), "I18N.Reactive", "{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}", GeneratesDesignTimeSource = true)]
public class I18NReactive : IVsSingleFileGenerator, IObjectWithSite
{
}
```

The source info came from this thread

https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/394

Comment: How did you get the .NET Standard Libraries to reference the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop package?  When I attempt to add the package using the Nuget Package Manager I get a message that the  VS Interop package is compatible with both .NET Standard and .NET Core libraries.

Comment: I was able to use FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC to enable it for .NET Core Console apps too